# Unable to connect Visual Basic application over SSL to AWS RDS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I've recently created a new RDS instance and am trying to edit a Visual Basic application to access the MySQL 8.0 database using an SSL connection.

Server side, everything seems to be okay. I have enabled `require_secure_transport` and have confirmed that I am able to connect via command line when supplying the cert file:

```
mysql -h database.server.123b234.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u user --ssl-ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --ssl-mode=REQUIRED -P 3306 -p
```

The visual basic application I am modifying is using a `MySql.Data.dll` library package with .NET framework at 6.7.4.0 in Visual Studio 2010. I have been playing around with the connection string, but I seem to consistently be receiving an exception `"A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception"` and Inner Exception being: `"The function requested is not supported"`

My connections string is:

```
myConnStr = "Server=database.server.123b234.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;" _
                & "uid=user;" _
                & "pwd=password;" _
                & "Port=3306;" _
                & "Allow Zero Datetime=true;" _
                & "CharSet=" & "utf8" _
                & "SSL Mode=Required"

// add to conn object
conn.ConnectionString = myConnStr
conn.Open()

// exception called on next step through code
```

I have been trying to figure out how to add the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` certificate to the connection string, but each time I try and add `ssl-ca` or `sslca` to the connection string with the RDS certificate specified, I receive an exception stating that the option does not exist.

Stack trace from SSPI exception:

```
{System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 
The function requested is not supported" & vbCrLf & "   
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---"
```

and

```
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I ended up upgrading the projects .NET Framework to v4.8, updating the MYSQL connector version (this was a pain) and to Visual Studio 2022. All works well now. Hopefully this will help someone down the line too.

Comment: I'm on v4.8 and mysql connector 8.1.0, but I cannot connect to a RDS instance running mysql 8.0 and have sslmode=required. Is your solution still working?